# Get 2d array from model, then pass from controller to view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I need to pass an array from my model (array is filled with info while reading a text file) to a controller and then finally to a view.

My model:

```
function show_notes()
{
    $file = "notes.txt";
    
    foreach(file($file) as $entry)
    {
        list($user, $content) = array_map('trim', explode(':', $entry));
        $notes = array (
            'user'=> '$user',
            'content'=> '$content'
        );
    }
    return $notes;
}
```

Controller:

```
function members_area()
{
    $this->load->model('Note_model');
    $notes[] = $this->Note_model->show_notes();
            
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('members_area', $notes);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');   
}
```

And in view, I use this:

```
foreach ($notes as $item) {
    echo "<h1>$user</h>";
    echo "<p>$content</p>";
}
```

And I am getting error that **notes** variable is undefined in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller:

```
$data['notes'] = $this->Note_model->show_notes();
... 
$this->load->view('members_area', $data);
```

EDIT:

In your view:

```
<?php foreach ($notes as $item):?>
   <h1><?php echo $item['user']; ?></h1>
   <p><?php echo $item['content'] ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In your model:

```
$notes = array();
foreach(file($file) as $entry)
{
        list($user, $content) = array_map('trim', explode(':', $entry));
        array_push($notes, array('user' => $user, 'content' => $content));
}
return $notes;
```

Comment: well it looks like this worked, but I get undefined content error now. It outputs my "user", but only the first one repeatedly

Comment: I have done as you suggested but I get error: ` array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Comment: Did you do `$notes = array();` before the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
$notes[] = $this->Note_model->show_notes();
```

with this

```
$notes['notes'] = $this->Note_model->show_notes();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The responsibility of the controller is to pass all required parameters to other layers (models/libraries/services/helpers/etc. -- a model method in your case) and either print a consumable payload in a desirable format (if, say, an API endpoint) or pass a payload of data to the view (to be rendered/formatted).
2. The model should be completely unaware of from where input data has been retrieved. In other words, a model method should never be accessing superglobals (like get, post, request, session, etc.).  Model methods should be build for utility so that they can be easily tested and called from various other places in the project.
3. The view layer should be doing little to no data processing (filtering, searching, restructuring, merging, sanitization, validation, and arithmetic should be avoided as much as possible). Interactions with data should be largely limited to essential looping, trivial conditions, and locale-specific formatting.

---

Your controller is calling `show_notes()`, then pushing the returned data as the first element of an array called `$notes`.  This is not going to serve your intention.

In your model method, you were not pushing newly encountered data as new elements in your `$notes` array, you were actually overwriting the same element each iteration.

For the view to be able to access a variable called `$notes`, the controller must pass an array with an element whose key is called `notes` as the second parameter of the view method call.
This is because when data is transferred from the controller to the view in CodeIgniter, the passed-in data is broken into individual variables based on the first level keys (see native PHP's `extract()` function to better understand the effect).

In the view's loop, `$user` and `$content` variables are never declared. You will need to declare these variables or access the associative values using array access syntax.

Here is my recommended re-write of your MVC methods:

- Controller

  ```
  public function members_area(): void
  {
       $this->load->model('Note_model');
       $data['notes'] = $this->Note_model->show_notes('file.txt');

       $this->load->view('includes/header');
       $this->load->view('members_area', $data);
       $this->load->view('includes/footer');   
  }
  ```
- Model

  ```
  public function show_notes(string $fileName): array
  {
      $notes = [];
      foreach(file($fileName) as $entry) {
          [$user, $content] = array_map('trim', explode(':', $entry));
          $notes[] = compact(['user', 'content']);
      }
      return $notes;
  }
  ```
- View

  ```
  foreach ($notes as ['user' => $user, 'content' => $content]) {
      echo "<h1>$user</h>";
      echo "<p>$content</p>";
  }
  ```